# Converting avi file to jpg gives black images

Tags: python, opencv, jpeg, avi

I'm using Python (Spyder 3) to convert an avi video into several jpegs frames using a code I found here:

```
    import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('1303_C_fond_149mm.avi')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
while success:
  cv2.imwrite("frame%d.png" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  print ('Read a new frame: ', success)
  count += 1
```

The thing is it create the right amount of frame, but they are only black ! I've watched the avi file, it's in black and white but works fine. The thing is I used the exact same code on an other set of data (avi file taken with a different camera), and it worked perfectly fine ! If you know why I can only get black pictures -of the right dimension- now, please let me know !

Comment: Try adding a line to print the shape of the frame after you read it so you can see if it has 1 or 3 channels `print(image.shape)`. Try also printing the brightest pixel in each frame so you can see if the input video frames are black `print(image[...,:].max())`

Comment: Just tried this: the inputs are all black (only 0)